# Unreachable Code error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, error-handling

I am making an app called ROME, about the city of Rome. I have a activity called eten which means food and I want the activity to open a certain pdf-file called etenlijst.pdf when openened.

I got to the following code:

```
package com.example.rome;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.net.Uri;
import java.io.File;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;



public class Eten extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eten);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    // getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_eten, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    Button OpenPDF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OpenPdfButton);
    OpenPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    { 
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            File pdfFile = new File("/ROME/Etenlijst.pdf"); 
            if(pdfFile.exists()) 
            {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
                Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try
                {
                    startActivity(pdfIntent);
                }
                catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Eten.this, "Installeer een geschikte applicatie om PDF's mee te openen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
   }
```

But at the line containing:         Button OpenPDF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OpenPdfButton);
        OpenPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

Eclipse gives me an error: Unreachable Code
I have no idea how to solve this, so I am asking you.
Do you know how to solve this and why this error comes up?

Thanks in advance,
Ide

P.S. I am not a native-English speaker so please look at my question and not at my grammar.

EDIT:

I got to the following now with your helpful answers:

```
package com.example.rome;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.net.Uri;
import java.io.File;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;



public class Eten extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_eten);
// Show the Up button in the action bar.
// getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    /****  This looks like a good place for it   *****/

   Button OpenPDF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OpenPdfButton);
    OpenPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    { 
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        File pdfFile = new File("/ROME/Etenlijst.pdf"); 
        if(pdfFile.exists()) 
        {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try
            {
                startActivity(pdfIntent);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Eten.this, "Installeer een geschikte applicatie om PDF's mee te openen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
        }

    }
});
}
}
```

But whenever I go to this activity in my app or click the button it won't open the file or give the toast?
Do you now why?

Answer (score 4):

After this line `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` which is just before the `Button OpenPDF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OpenPdfButton);`, the function would return and hence the next line (and all lines after that) would not be executed.

Your logic should be such that `return` should be the last statement of the block it occurs in.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to be in that method if it isn't an option button. Move it to `onCreate()` if it isn't an option but a regular `Button`

```
public class Eten extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eten);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    // getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



/****  This looks like a good place for it   *****/

   Button OpenPDF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OpenPdfButton);
    OpenPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    { 
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            File pdfFile = new File("/ROME/Etenlijst.pdf"); 
            if(pdfFile.exists()) 
            {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
                Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try
                {
                    startActivity(pdfIntent);
                }
                catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Eten.this, "Installeer een geschikte applicatie om PDF's mee te openen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

if it is an option then use your `switch`

```
case (R.id.idOfThisOption):
//don't need onClick()...just put the functionality here
File pdfFile = new File("/ROME/Etenlijst.pdf"); 
        if(pdfFile.exists()) 
        {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try
            {
                startActivity(pdfIntent);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Eten.this, "Installeer een geschikte applicatie om PDF's mee te openen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
        }
break;
```

Comment: The code is in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method.  Your explanation is incorrect.

Comment: @rgettman yes, I see now, thanks. I guess I saw the `return` and assumed it was the end of the function and they forgot to add the `}` And naturally the `Button` in there through me off. Anyway, I have updated my answer

Comment: You should include the `@Override` annotation above the `onClick()` method. Besides that I would have to know more about what's going on such as is it crashing? If so include error logs. Does it ever enter the method. If adding the annotation doesn't fix it then please accept one of the answers and post a new question as this is a separate issue and I will be happy to look at it